# Spring controller - %2F in get parameter

Tags: spring-mvc

Client want to send slash in get parameter

http://localhost/controller/getvalue/hello%2Fworld

so I need to get this "hello%2Fworld" as string parameter. I enabled AllowUrlEncodedSlash and other things, but I always getting exception

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hello/world"
```

Why Spring trying to convert this into integer ? And why was %2F automatically converted?

Comment: What is the method signature of the REST endpoint?

Comment: That's not a `GET` parameter but rather the path variable. The rest controller has to be set up in `@RequestMapping(value = "/controller/getvalue/{val}"...` way, whereas the `val` is expected to be well-formed string